# std::priority_queue bug/problem in MSVC++ 2008/2010 Debug configuration

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Briefly, my question is somewhat language-lawyerly: is the following issue a bug in MSVC++, or "acceptable" behavior?

After encountering a nasty access violation in someone's code, I tracked the source of the problem to the debug implementation of `std::priority_queue<>` in MSVS.  (I have verified that the problem exists in both 2008 and 2010.)  Following is boiled-down sample code that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

struct Less_than
{
    bool operator() (const int *x, const int *y) const
    {
        std::cout << "Less_than(" << *x << ", " << *y << ")" << std::endl;
        return *x < *y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int *, std::vector<int *>, Less_than> q;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    q.push(&x);
    q.push(&y);
    std::cout << "Popping " << *q.top() << "..." << std::endl;
    q.pop();
}
```

The output should be (and is, in the Release build configuration):

```
Less_than(0, 1)
Popping 1...
```

However, in the Debug build configuration, the output is:

```
Less_than(0, 1)
Less_than(1, 0)
Popping 1...
Less_than(1, 0)
```

The key difference is the final additional comparison that occurs as a side effect of pop().  In the Debug build, when pop()ing the top element from the queue, the pop() implementation first *compares* the top element to every other element in the queue to verify that it is indeed the maximal element.

This would obviously be a problem (and *was* the problem in the code in question) if, as in the above example, you were using a priority_queue of pointers to objects with your own comparison... but were also *removing* objects with the following:

```
delete pq.top();
pq.pop();
```

Here, we release the object pointed to by pq.top(), but then when we try to pop() the pointer from the queue, the Debug implementation of pop() first tries to compare the now-invalid object pointed to by top() to everything else in the queue!

Of course, a simple solution is to simply replace the above with:

```
T *p = pq.top();
pq.pop();
delete p;
```

But my question is: technically, shouldn't the original code work as well?  Put more precisely, should we be able to depend on pop() *not comparing* the current top element to anything in the process of removing it?  I read the standard as being pretty precise here; the relevant sections of C++03 are 25.2.3.2.2 (`pop()`) and 25.3.6.2 (`pop_heap()`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why on earth are you using `int*` here? This is a recipe for mistakes. One of which you probably cooked up here.

Comment: This is just an example to demonstrate the problem.  More generally, the problem is when you have a `priority_queue<T *>`, where `T` being something more than just an `int` is not as far-fetched.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your code `T *p = pq.top();` is wrong. You get a const& to an item in your queue. But you delete the object you get. So basically you made the object in your queue invalid.
So this is a dangerous thing. I would avoid doing such things.

Comment: Note that the queue does not contain the "object" (i.e., the instance of type `T`), it contains a *pointer* to the object.  So you're right, by delete-ing before pop-ing, the queue now contains an invalid *pointer*.  But my question isn't about danger or propriety, it's about whether the compiler is doing something that the standard explicitly/implicitly prohibits.

Comment: Whether or not the standard prohibits, common sense suggests to me that deleting something that is referenced from a still-valid queue element is not a great idea. The result is the dreaded undefined behaviour, I would expect.

Comment: Agreed.  But this does not answer my question.  The question was, *whether or not the standard prohibits.*  Note, for example, that the O(lg n) run time of `pop` is specified explicitly.

Comment: @possiblywrong: I was a little sketchy about object and pointer, sorry for that. But I looked through the standard and I did not find anything that directly prohibits this behavior, but I assume you did the same and I am not the standard wise guy. So from how I read the standard the behavior is ok. But I agree it is interesting to know.